# Inquiry on the Chebyshev $\theta$ function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let 
$$\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} \log p$$ be the Chebyshev function over primes $p$.

Computational evidence seems to suggest that $\theta(x) < x$ for every sufficiently large $x$.

But is it true ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Littlewood proved that $\theta(x) > x + c \sqrt{x} \log \log \log x$ holds for infinitely many integers $x$, for some $c > 0$. Cf the answer to [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178635/lower-bounds-on-the-error-term-of-the-prime-number-theorem), noting that $\theta(x) = \psi(x) + O(\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 0):

In [an answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227887/when-is-chebyshevs-varthetaxx) someone speculates that the first time this happens is "basically around the Skewes number  $1.4 \times 10^{316}.$"